# jquery regex can't match my numerical value

Tags: jquery, regex

I move some rows from a table to another, and I need to modify the content during the operation. The matching selection should only contains an index (numerical). It is usually at the beginning, but I added the class to be sure to match the good one in the whole row.

```
$linehtml.replace('/<td class="index">[0-9]+</td>/', '<td>foo</td>');
```

I tried with:

```
'/<td class="index">[0-9]+</td>/'

'<td class="index">/[0-9]+/</td>'
```

I should be ok according to http://regexpal.com/, but something looks wrong with the jquery regex.

Here is an example:

```
<td class="index">5</td> <td>11</td> <td>History</td> <td id="description_5">here is the description</td>
```

It should looks like that at the end:

```
<td>foo</td> <td>11</td> <td>History</td> <td id="description_5">here is the description</td>
```

Edit:

My aim is to move a row from a second table to a first one: http://jsfiddle.net/k53Pz/2/

Click on the "Click to add" cell (sorry it is in French, I created the Fiddle fast because I just started this workflow. Maybe it isn't a good method to do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript supports regexes as literals, so don't quote them. e.g.

```
s.replace(/<td class="index">[0-9]+<\/td>/, '<td>foo</td>');
```

Keeping in mind that you need to escape your forward slashes and whatnot.

By quoting them, you're saying to treat it as a normal string, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery why use regex at all?

```
$('.index').html('foo').removeAttr('class');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/k53Pz/

Comment: sorry, because I would keep the orinal row in the original table, I simply make a copy. So I did $(".add").click(function() {
   //we get the line
   var $line = $(this).parent();

Comment: What I am doing doesn't remove the original row. You need to show us some more of your code so that we know what we are looking to answer.

Comment: I mean, I have two tables:
The first one wait to receive rows.
The second one, when you clik on a cell on a row, it will add a modified version of this row the the first table. So I work on a copy of the row that I finally add to my table with ".append". Maybe  it isn't a good method to do that...

Comment: Can you describe fully what you're doing in your post? Otherwise we would be guessing at how to answer. You're giving a lot of information that you should have given in your original post. Can you edit your post please?

Comment: This is what I wanted to do. Sorry to don't be enough accurate: http://jsfiddle.net/k53Pz/3/